# How to fix 'RaisedButton' error in Flutter using CustomButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm encountering the following errors in my Flutter project while trying to implement a `CustomButton` widget:

1. "The method `RaisedButton` isn't defined for the type `CustomButton`"
2. "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked"
3. "Undefined name `text`"

**Code:**

```
(dart)
  class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  final String Text;
  const CustomButton({required this.onTap, required this.Text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 200,
      child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: onTap,
      child: Text(text,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

**How to solve the issues?** Thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have extra ")". Try removing one and it should work. Also, prefer using ElevatedButton. RaisedButton is depreciated.
2. Function onTap is not a function. Replace it with Function()? onTap
3. You have type (final String Text). make it final String text